# cmake FetchContent_MakeAvailable does not populate variables

Tags: boost, cmake

I'm using `FetchContent` to add boost as external project dependency to my project, but I found that the boost library hasn't been populated by `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`.

I want to use `FetchContent` to add boost as dependency to my project. Here is my `CMakeCode` to do that:

```
include(FetchContent)

set(BOOST_INCLUDE_LIBRARIES math filesystem system program_options asio)
set(BOOST_ENABLE_CMAKE ON)

FetchContent_Declare(
    Boost
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/boost
    URL https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.74.0/source/boost_1_74_0.tar.gz
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Boost)


get_cmake_property(_variableNames VARIABLES)
list (SORT _variableNames)
foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
    string(FIND "${_variableName}" "BOOST" out)
    if ("${out}" EQUAL 0)
        message(STATUS "vriables => ${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
    endif()
endforeach()
```

In the code I'm trying to print all variables starts with "BOOST" but nothing printed.

Am I missing any necessary statements in my CMake code?

Comment: Why do you expect `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Boost)` to create any variable in the current scope? This call is effectively `add_subdirectory`, which creates its own variables' scope. "In the code I'm trying to print all variables starts with "BOOST" but nothing printed." - You manually create variables `BOOST_INCLUDE_LIBRARIES` and `BOOST_ENABLE_CMAKE`, and even they are not printed? FetchContent is definitely not responsible for that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for reply,  I just misunderstand the ability of FetchContent_MakeAvailable.